# How do I initialize 'inline' an array of arrays in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, multidimensional-array

new bee in Kotlin and I am trying to compile a very simple thing. I'd like to initialize an array of lists with one line of code. But I get stuck in always have to uses mutable objects and inserts unto the list.

Here what I have which *I don't like*. It is too complicated and many lines of code, the array does not need to be mutable in reality. It will be always the same size and same number of elements.

```
val r0 = arrayListOf<Int>(1, 3, 5, 7)
val r1 = arrayListOf<Int>(10, 11, 16, 20)
val r2 = arrayListOf<Int>(23, 30, 34, 60)

val list: MutableList<ArrayList<Int>> = ArrayList()
list.add(r0)
list.add(r1)
list.add(r2)
```

That works, but I want something like

```
val list2: List<ArrayList<Int>> = ArrayList(
    arrayListOf<Int>(1, 3, 5, 7),
    arrayListOf<Int>(10, 11, 16, 20),
    arrayListOf<Int>(23, 30, 34, 60)
)
```

But this does not compile, not sure why.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking your original of:

```
val list2: List<ArrayList<Int>> = ArrayList(
    arrayListOf<Int>(1, 3, 5, 7),
    arrayListOf<Int>(10, 11, 16, 20),
    arrayListOf<Int>(23, 30, 34, 60)
)
```

I modified it to this, the kotlin constructors almost always follow `arrayListOf` nomenclature, and you had `ArrayList` on the first line after the `=`

```
val list2: ArrayList<ArrayList<Int>> = arrayListOf(
    arrayListOf(1, 3, 5, 7),
    arrayListOf(10, 11, 16, 20),
    arrayListOf(23, 30, 34, 60)
)
```

The types are not necessary on each internal list, since you've declared them at the variable

Other examples of constructors using this pattern:

`listOf, mutableListOf, intArrayOf, booleanArrayOf`

Some non similar constructors:

`arrayOfNulls, emptyArray, emptyList`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way:

```
val list2: List<List<Int>> = listOf(
    listOf(1, 3, 5, 7),
    listOf(10, 11, 16, 20),
    listOf(23, 30, 34, 60)
)
```